# Is it possible to charge payment before Silverlight OOB instalation

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have written an application in Silverlight 5 in which I want to attach to a web site from where the user will have the option to install an OOB version of the app to their machine. The application idea was three years in the making so I want to charge a fee to the user before installation of the application. To write the Silverlight application I had to learn to program from a book and on line tutorials (Silverlight 5 VB). If there is anyone out there that could give me some pointers on this matter I would be very grateful.

Kind regards
Will.

Comment: It is certainly possible. What have you done already?

Comment: Al I have done to date is written the app. At the present time I'm looking into building a web site in which I can attach the application to. The web site will be entirely based on and around the application itself. What I am trying to do is get everything code wise with the app finished, so, if the payment system is done by code (In which I can add something like paypal) I'd like to get it all done now. It would be nice if when the user right clicks to get the option to install OOB to their machine they can be directed to paypal (Or similar) for payment details before installation.

Comment: You can start the OOB install from code (as long as it's from so-called 'user-initiated' action), so that mean you scenario should be doable.

Comment: What I wanted to stress is: it is very hard to secure your app against piracy, both unauthorized execution and decompilation. You have to account for that.

Comment: Hi jv42, thanks for getting back to me. I suppose once a user has got it onto their machine and they know what they are doing it could be a free for all unless well protected. It would be nice to know if there is any one out there that has actually done this procedure with some success. Never the less, I will have a look at start the OOB install from code, ("I've got my book Pro Silverlight 5 in VB") this seems to give a detailed account of the task but I'm still not sure about  how to add a payment system.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833066%28v=vs.95%29.aspx might help also.